# Twitter in 2013

Tags: twitter

I am a geography teacher and would love to map tweets in QGIS for my pupils. I followed all the instructions but it seems Twitter have changed the way they stream their tweets. I can cope with the GIS side but I am not a Twitter developer. Is there any advice you can give a very busy teacher on getting those tweets?

Comment: You may find this Stack Overflow question relevant (it's from December 2012): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812579/twitter-api-location-of-tweets

Doesn't look like it has changed since then.

Answer (score 4):

I used to do this with curl as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337319/how-to-search-only-for-geotagged-tweets), but
Twitter removed basic authentication support from public streaming endpoints on June 11, 2013, so you need to use [OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq). In order to do this you need to have a Twitter account and [request an application](https://dev.twitter.com/apps).

Below is a very simple example, written in Python using the [twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) library.

```
from twython import TwythonStreamer

# supply your OAuth values below
APP_KEY = 'xxxx' 
APP_KEY_SECRET = 'xxxx'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxx'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxx'

class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
    def on_success(self, data):
        if 'coordinates' in data:
             try:                 
                 print 'lat: ', data['coordinates']['coordinates'][0], 'lon: ', data['coordinates']['coordinates'][1],  '\n'
             except:
                  pass

    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
        print status_code, data

stream = MyStreamer(APP_KEY,
        APP_KEY_SECRET,
        ACCESS_TOKEN,
        ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

stream.statuses.filter(locations='-180,-90,180,90')
```

If Python is not your language of choice, there are [other options](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any programming language whatsoever, you could try something like [Geofeedia](http://corp.geofeedia.com/request-a-trial/) (see below), which would allow you to look at Twitter and other social media feeds in a geographic context. The website has a closed Beta right now, but you can [apply for access](http://corp.geofeedia.com/request-a-trial/).

[image]